# WiFi authentication not accepted on samsung nc10

Tags: wireless

So, im a complete ubuntu/linux noob. I installed 12.04 on my Samsung NC10 and it keeps asking for password authentication when connecting to wifi, I know the password is correct and the wifi worked fine in Windows XP. I looked on some other posts but am a bit lost as they all seemed to have different answers, before I go typing things into the terminal I shouldnt can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung N110 and had a similar problem.  I found that I clicked on the edit connection tab, told it to ignore IP6, and chose manual for IP4 (and inserted an IP address, subnet mask, gateway address, and DNS server) clicked save and it connected right away and I have had no problems since.